# How to set PIL saved image "content type" as 'image/jpeg'?

Tags: firebase, python-imaging-library, firebase-storage

I'm reading an image with `PIL`, resizing it, and saving again as `jpeg`, as such:

```
img = np.array(Image.open(filename))
# I'm using TensorFlow for resizing, but it doesn't matter
resized_img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.smart_resize(img, (335, 335))
resized_img = Image.fromarray(resized_img.astype('uint8')).convert('RGB')

resized_img.save(f'thumb/{filename}_thumb', format='jpeg', quality=70)
```

When I upload it to Firebase Storage and I try to access it with the direct link, the file gets downloaded instead of displaying the image, which is something I don't want.

It can be viewed locally normally. But the Type is shown as `application/octet-stream` at the console, and it can also be displayed normally with `<img>` tags.

EDIT: I could solve the content type problem by using

`gsutil -m -h "Content-Type:image/jpeg" cp -r . gs://mybucket.appspot.com`

when transferring the images. But the problem isn't solved, the images continue to be downloaded automatically when accessed with the direct link.

Comment: Try adding the `.jpg` extension to the filename after `thumb` when saving.

Comment: It does solve the problem(!), but I don't want to have the extension, since the original images don't have it and I wanted to keep the naming pattern. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Firebase.